# How to read items in a text file and overwrite it based on the user's inputs

Tags: python, function

Please let me know if my question is correct
Context:
This function view_mine(), needs to be able to

1. List the tasks of the user that is currently logged. It reads the information from a task.txt and checks if the username that has been input at the beginning (login) matches with the corresponding task in txt, then prints it (I have done this)
2. The function must also give the user the ability to select a task they are assigned by the user inputting a task number displayed. The user should be allowed to edit the task only if it is not completed. There are two main edits:

2.1. Edit the task
2.1.1. Username change - change the username and write the new username to
the task.txt file
2.1.2. Due date change - same as above

2.2. Mark the task complete- change the 'No', to a 'Yes"

I have kind of managed to do from point 2 onwards, but what I am unable to do is to go the task in the txt and overwrite what has been edited.

How do I make my program identify the task by matching the given task number with the line in the txt, then replace what the user would like to replace and overwrite the txt.

If the given txt is:

admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No
admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No
abc, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No

And I would like to edit the username of task 1, which is the first line, to john. It should look like this after

John, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No
admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No
abc, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No

```
> #This program is a task manager for a small business and allows the user
#to add and assign tasks to users, as well as add new users


#======== User Login ====================

#read the use.txt
username_reg = []
password_reg = []
username_list = []
password_list = []

with open('user.txt', 'r+') as f:           #open user.txt
    for line in f:                          #Now we reading user.txt
        line = line.replace(" ", "")        #replace space before password with no space
        line = line.replace("\n", "")       #remove the next line character as this will take a space in the list
        line = line.split(",")              #separate user name and password
        username_reg = line[0]
        password_reg = line[1]
        username_list.append(username_reg)
        password_list.append(password_reg)

print(username_list)
print(password_list)
print(len(username_list))
username = input("Please enter username: ")
password = input("Please enter password: ")


i = 0; login = 0 #Here login is like a flag. Which get the value 1 once the login is successful else stays 0.
while i < len(username_list):
    if username == str(username_list[i]) and password == str(password_list[i]):
        login = 1
        if username == "admin":
            selection = input('''Please select one of the following options:
                             r - register user
                             a - add task
                             va - view all tasks
                             vm - view my tasks
                             gr - generate reports
                             ds - display statistics
                             e - exit\n''')
        else:
            selection = input('''Please select one of the following options:
                             a - add task
                             va - view all tasks
                             vm - view my tasks
                             e - exit\n''')
            
        break
    i+=1
    if i==len(username_list) and login == 0:
        print("invalid username or password")   
        username = input("Please enter username: ")
        password = input("Please enter password: ")
        i = 0

##=====================View My Tasks Function====================
def view_mine():
    num_task_list = []  #This is the list for the Task Numbers
    f = open('tasks.txt', 'r+')
    row = f.readlines()
    num_task = 0
    for i in row:
        task = i.replace(" ", "")
        task = i.replace("\n","")
        task = i.split(",")
        num_task +=1
        num_task_list.append(num_task)
        if username == task[0]:
            sentence = (f'''
                            Task Number     : {num_task}
                            Task assigned to: {task[0]}
                            Task title      : {task[1]}
                            Task descrition : {task[2]}
                            Due Date        : {task[3]}
                            Date Assigned   : {task[4]}
                            Completed       : {task[5]}\n''')
            print(sentence)
    
#This part of the code is supposed to ask the user(only the user that is logged in) which task they would like to edit
#They would select a number, then I would
    TaskNum = int(input("Please select Task Number you would like to edit: "))  #user inputs the task they would like to edit
    for j in range(0, len(num_task_list),1):
        
        if TaskNum == num_task_list[j]:    #This checks the task number against the list for task numbers
            editOption = input('''Would you like to:
                                   e - edit task
                                   c - mark complete
                                   -1- return to main menu\n''')

            if editOption == "e":
                if task[5]=="yes":
                    print("Task completed, no further changes allowed")
                else:
                    edit = input('''What would you like to edit:
                                             u - username
                                             d - due date\n''')
                    if edit == "u":
                        task[0] = input("Please input new user: ")
                        f.write(task[0])
                                
                    else:
                        task[3] = input("Please in put new due date (dd MMM yyyy):")
                        f.write(task[3])
                        
            elif editOption == "c":
                        task[5] = input("Please type 'Yes' if task is completed: ")
                        f.write(task[5])    
            #elif editOption == "-1"

    f.close()  
#===============view my tasks (vm)======
if selection == "vm":
    view_mine()

**task.txt file:**(Each task is in one line)
admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No
admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No
abc, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No

**user.txt**
admin, adm1n
abc, defg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating files, the more secure way to go is to create a temporal file where you write the content, while you keep the original safe and untouched. Then, when the writing process is done, you can remove the original and rename the temporal file.

Also, I think you should have some sort of unique ID that identifies each task. I had to use the row number to identify them, but it would be better if you include some immutable ID.

Finally, I suggest you to use a dictionary instead of a list when fetching the tasks. It allows you to access and update the fields more easily.

*(In the example below, I didn't include all the menu options, I only included the username edit to illustrate how it should work)*

```
import os
from pprint import pprint

# The view_mine function should receive the username as a parameter
def view_mine(username):
    tasks = []
    i = 0
    with open('tasks.txt') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for db_row, line in enumerate(lines):
        assigned_to, *rest = line.split(', ')
        if username == assigned_to:
            # use a dictionary to easily refer to the taks' fields
            data = {k: v for k, v in zip(
                ('number', 'db_row', 'assigned_to', 'title', 'description',
                 'due_date', 'date_assigned', 'completed'),
                (i + 1, db_row, assigned_to, *rest))}
            tasks.append(data)
            i += 1
    # You can customize what you want to print, I just used pprint as a shortcut for this example
    pprint(tasks)
    task_num = int(input("Please select Task Number you would like to edit: "))
    # Get specific task at given index
    task = tasks[task_num - 1]
    edit_option = input('''Would you like to:
                                   e - edit task
                                   c - mark complete
                                   -1- return to main menu\n''')
    if edit_option == 'e':
        # This is how you would refer to the fields
        if task['completed'] == 'No':
            edit = input('''What would you like to edit:
                                             u - username
                                             d - due date\n''')
            if edit == "u":
                        # updating a field
                        task['assigned_to'] = input("Please input new user: ")

    # Actual file update part
    fetched_rows = [task['db_row'] for task in tasks]
    with open('tasks.txt') as f, open('temp.txt', 'w') as t:
        for db_row, line in enumerate(f):
            if db_row in fetched_rows:
                fetched_rows.remove(db_row)
                print(', '.join(v for k, v in list(tasks.pop(0).items())[2:]), file=t)
            else:
                print(line.strip(), file=t)
    
    os.remove('tasks.txt')
    os.rename('temp.txt', 'tasks.txt')
```